# organizing fabric tasks in python modules

Tags: fabric

I have task A in a.py, B in b.py and task B executes A, hence there's an 'import a' in b.py.

when I do 'fab --list', I get a.A, b.B and b.a.A.  How can I avoid b.a.A in the fab list? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit what fabric will display in `fab -l` by limiting the functions that exported from your modules. A good description of this is given in the fabric documentation for [defining tasks](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/tasks.html#namespaces) (specifically the sections on [namespaces](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/tasks.html#namespaces) and [Limiting with `__all__`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/tasks.html#limiting-with-all).

If you've got your fabfile in a directory something like this:

```
.
└── fabfile
    ├── a.py
    ├── b.py
    └── __init__.py
```

The brute force way to do this is via renaming in `__init__.py`:

```
import a
import b    
A = a.A
B = b.B
```

In `a.py` (and `b.py`) you block the export of all functions with `__all__`

```
from fabric.api import *

@task
def A():
    pass

__all__ = []
```

Next time you run `fab -l` you should get the correct results

```
$ fab -l
Available commands:

    A
    B
```

However, it's worth thinking about whether this is something you want to do. Typically if you've got enough functionality to make reading the output of fabric difficult, you may want to consider whether you legitimately want to run those functions as tasks in the first place.

An alternative to the `__all__` hack is to get fabric to present the tasks in a different format that, might be, more readable

```
$ fab --list-format=nested --list

Available commands (remember to call as module.[...].task):

    A
    B
    a:
        A
    b:
        B
```